# A primitive element in $F_2$ cannot contain both $x$ and $x^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Suppose $w$ is a non-empty cyclically reduced word in the alphabet $\lbrace x,y,x^{-1},y^{-1}\rbrace$ and that $w$ represents a primitive element of $\langle x,y\rangle\cong F_2$. Why is it that $w$ cannot contain, say, both $x$ and $x^{-1}$? I can't find a source on this that doesn't delve into the fully general case of $F_n$. I am not super familiar with group theory, and I just want to understand why this specific statement holds. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit out of practice for groups, but doesn't $w=xyx^{-1}$ work?

Comment: The *cyclically reduced* adjective deals with this case; since $yx^{-1}x$ is not reduced.

Comment: [This paper of Piggott](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504401.pdf) contains a description and a reference. But let me say that this fact is very particular to the study of the group $F_2$: it's false for free groups of rank $\ge 3$; and there's nothing particularly like this fact in the broader realm of group theory. The proof I can think of does share tools with the study of higher rank free groups, namely Whitehead graphs and Whitehead's algorithm.

Comment: Wonderful @LeeMosher, thank you.